# integration,how to iterate string json values in apex class so that i can insert json values into clubspeed

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger EventCallout on Event (before insert) {


String jsonevents=Json.serialize(Trigger.new[0]);
ClubSpeedup.thePosting(jsonevents);
```

This is my apex class

```
public with sharing class ClubSpeedup {
//public String thePosting {get;set;}
//public String postingbody{get;set;}
    @future(callout=true)

public static void thePosting(String MyEvents){

    String endpoint = 'http://k1irvine.clubspeedtiming.com/api/index.php/events?key=CL3EuX4ttPHpXMB9xuZwHT';

    //Map<Id,Event> eventMap=new Map<ID,Event>([select Id, Subject, isAllDayEvent, StartDateTime, EndDateTime from Event]);
    //String EventJson=JSON.serialize(eventMap.values());

    String body ='{"memberOnly":"false","eventTheme":-6697728,"totalRacers":200,"eventDesc":"test","EventTypeName":"A&D","eventDuration":200,"eventScheduledTime":"2006-05-26T16:10:00.00"}';
    HttpRequest reqst = new HttpRequest();
    reqst.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    reqst.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    reqst.setbody(MyEvents);
    reqst.setMethod('POST');
    Http h = new Http();
    reqst.setTimeout(100000);
    HTTPResponse response = h.send(reqst);
    List<Event> eventreturn = (List<Event>)Json.deserialize(MyEvents,List<Event>.class);
    //return (ClubSpeedup) System.JSON.deserialize(MyEvents, ClubSpeedup.class);

    //postingbody = response.getBody();
    //System.debug('*****'+response);

    }
```

Comment: And what is you question about the code you posted?

Comment: i want to insert salesforce event fields into clubspeed  events by clicking on standard Event save button.I tried to write trigger in Event and passed serialize event fields json to my apex class method theposting .Now i want to itretate the json string and mapp it into clubspeed event fields

Comment: In this ,String body ='{"memberOnly":"false","eventTheme":-6697728,"totalRacers":200,"eventDesc":"test","EventTypeName":"A&D","eventDuration":200,"eventScheduledTime":"2006-05-26T16:10:00.00"}';it is the clubspeed event values which is different from salesforce event fields .